# How to locate the upload button related to the text Upload Image as per the HTML?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm using Selenium with Firefox (I've tried chrome but the success ratio on this one was significantly lower). I'm trying to locate an element (upload button) and the success ratio is nowhere near an acceptable percentage.

Now I know that I could try to use just selenium to the **input** but it wont locate it as well no matter what I do. So I used AutoIt for the uploading part.

```
frdriver.get('')
time.sleep(11)
try:
    # el = WebDriverWait(frdriver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/i[2]')))
    el = frdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/i[2]')

    try:
        el.click()
        print(el)
        #ActionChains(frdriver).move_to_element(el).click().perform()
        try:
            #element = WebDriverWait(frdriver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]')))

            element = frdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]')
            time.sleep(4)
            try:
                element.click()
                #ActionChains(frdriver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
                autoit.run("/image.exe")
                r = 100
            except:
                print('Firefox retries upload')
                r += 1
        except:
            print('Firefox retries upload')
            r += 1
    except:
        print('Firefox retries upload')
        r += 1
except:
    print('Firefox retries upload')
    r += 1
```

As you can see I've tried many ways, each one had almost the same success. 
I'm using a remote windows machine for the job and it really might be my idea, but when it isn't minimized it works a lot better.

Also there is something else, for some reason there are times that even if it hasn't successfully clicked a button it bypasses the try/except and proceeds.

**Edit** html of the page

```
<div class="ui-searchbar-keyword-panel ui-searchbar-keyword-hide ui-searchbar-static" style="z-index: 99; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 35px;" data-widget-cid="widget-7">
    <div class="ui-searchbar-img-search-box">
        <div class="icbu-w-image-uploader-panel">
            <div class="icbu-w-image-uploader-content">
                <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                    <div class="upload-btn" data-spm-anchor-id="a2700.8293689.scGlobalHomeHeader.i1.2ce265aarlKA3D" style="z-index: 1;">Upload Image</div>
                    <div id="html5_1cjiqdvveht51pom1nbkqoiaop3_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 14px; left: 224px; width: 109px; height: 28px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;">
                        <input id="html5_1cjiqdvveht51pom1nbkqoiaop3" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="response-text">Max 2MB per Image</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="J-box-loadding-mask box-loadding-mask" data-role="loading" style="display: none;">
        <div class="mh-mamo-loadding-box">
            <i class="mh-mamo-icon-loadding"></i>
            <span class="J-loading-text mh-mamo-loadding-text">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share HTML code sample or/and page URL

Comment: @Andersson Just did hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use `driver.implicitly_wait(X)` where X is a number of seconds instead of reinventing the wheel with using `time.sleep` and retrying. That will increase selenium's tolerance towards the page loading and you will have better success in finding page elements.

Comment: @bowo229 I used 
WebDriverWait(frdriver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located...
Will try what you suggested but I doubt it will have a significant effect
the reason I'm asking is because I tried with selenium's elements wait. Anyway I'll give you a heads up if it does

Comment: @bowo229 Like I said nothing changed

Comment: I tried using a regular setup of chromedriver without headless and I can upload using driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input').click().
Try downloading the html of the target page and use your script on the offline copy in order to make sure that your script works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the *upload button* related to the text **Upload Image** you can use the following solution:

- `XPATH`:

  ```
  upload_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='upload-btn-wrapper']//div[@class='moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5' and starts-with(@id,'html5_')]/input[starts-with(@id,'html5_')]"))).click()
  ```
- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  upload_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.upload-btn-wrapper div.moxie-shim.moxie-shim-html5[id^='html5_']>input[id^='html5_']"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```